# I'm missing application search function in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

After **upgrade to 22.10 gone wrong** (so no 22.10 - my current version is 22.04), I lost my desktop. After reinstalling it, everything works fine but:

- there is no desktop application search functionality
- there is no Show application (9dots icon)

I guess issues could be related. Does anyone have idea how to bring them back?

ps: I think that this part is not related to the question but any way. As Rishon JR stated "sudo do-release-upgrade". So how this could go wrong?

```
Reading state information... Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree... Done
```

So after some research I found that I should uninstall not upgradable packages and retry. And so it happens that I uninstalled xserver. But after reinstalling it, not everything works as it should. So the question is how to get back application search.

apt.log & main.log:

https://we.tl/t-w0q83Xqt9k

Comment: which version? 22.04 or 22.10. You question is not clear. [edit] to indicate what you did to upgrade and how it went wrong.

Comment: Probably he tried to run `sudo do-release-upgrade` and some error occurred. That's what I think he meant

Comment: There are many ways that it could go wrong. a corrupt package, a corrupt sector on HDD/SSD, a sudden network outage, the download servers could be down, and a lot more.(it can also be caused by compatibility issues as well as per my observation with old laptops)

Comment: I'd say "compatibility issues" since laptop is almost new XPS and I tried to upgrade because of constant sound issues (jack works, then not, then yes...) and there are some other issues with hardware and I'd like to have some new features and perhaps find window tiling (it does not work since I upgraded to 21.04 and it still doesn't). Thanks for your answer I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: According to apt.log, it has upgraded your whole desktop and some other packages like gcc. And why did you abort the process?

Answer (score 2):

There Are 2 Routes to this.
An Obvious route would be back backup and reinstall.
The other route is to reinstall the packages. It depends on how much you have upgraded.
**1) If you have only upgraded only the desktop:**
Run

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt reinstall gdm3 ubuntu-gnome-desktop ubuntu-desktop
```

**2)If you have upgraded multiple Packages**
Reinstall all the upgrade packages by Doing

```
sudo apt purge <PACKAGES>
sudo apt install <packages>
```

Then

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt reinstall gdm3 ubuntu-gnome-desktop ubuntu-desktop
```

If it also installs a newer kernel(5.19.x), Then remove it by

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-header-*
dpkg -l | grep linux-image-*
```

Then remove all the 5.19.x kernels by `sudo apt purge <KERNEL>` From the output above.
After that, reboot.
If the problem still persists, attach a log of dist-upgrade(`/var/log/dist-upgrade`) and I will edit the answer and try my best to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this is one of those silly mistakes. I was logged in "Gnome Classic" and after re-login into "Gnome", everything works well.

Comment: Good to hear that your system is fine now.